# Laravel 5.2: While moving to production, class "Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider" not found in vendor folder

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravelcollective

I have been trying to move my laravel app to production. I following below steps

```
1. git clone
2. composer install
3. set env variables
4. (artisan key:generate)
5. artisan migrate --seed
```

But when i ran composer install, am getting the following error

> Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146

I know this error means, laravelcollective not added in composer.json and need to following steps as mentioned [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-collective-class-form-not-found?page=1)

But i already have done the same thing in dev mode and now the composer.json has require "laravelcollective" and aliases in config/app.php.

My question is, do i need to the same thing what i have done in dev (resolving laravelcollective issue) for every new production instance that i am gonna set it up ?

Comment: @oseintow, instead of composer install ?. tried instead of composer install, but getting the error. I think composer install only need to be run, then only it can create .env file.

Answer (score 0):

if your project working fine locally, then you have to Run `composer update` commend under your project repo. did you uploaded vender folder?

Also try to upload(only) `vender/composer` folder into your `vender, and then try to run`composer install`or`update` command

Comment: i didn't upload vendor folder  to keep project size in minimal.

Comment: just create `vender` directory and upload only `composer` directory, then try it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

this should install all the dependencies without problem

Answer (score 0):

update it in your composer.json file.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
},
```

then in run command 'composer update' after it add dependancy in you app/config/app.php file..

Comment: Its already added. while composer install/update gives the same error